# Is there a formula to get the answer of $a^1+a^2+a^3+\cdots+a^k\pmod{10^9+7}$?

Tags: number-theory

Hi so I am working on a problem where I have to calculate  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a^i$ modulo $10^9+7$.

I have to do this on a computer, so I have to avoid overflow. I was wondering if there will be a formula that can help me with my problem.

Comment: Is $|a| \lt 1$?

Comment: No,$a>=1$ and $a<=10^9$

Comment: @sbp That's irrelevant.

Comment: @sbp: Did you notice that it's a finite sum? Whether $|a|<1$ only matters for the infinite sum.

Comment: @Henrik: Didnt notice that. My bad. Apologies.

Comment: Any bounds on $n$?

Comment: $n$ is smaller or equal to $10^9+7$

Answer (score 6):

in general, if $a\neq 1$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{a^{n+1} -1}{a-1}$$
For a proof, multiply by $a-1$ and observe the "telescopic" behavior of the lhs.

(Note that the sum starts with $k=0$, not $k=1$ as in your case).